# Content Security Policy object cannot be whitelisted in Firefox

Tags: html, firefox, svg, content-security-policy

Currently am I working on adding Content Security Policy (CSP) headers to an already existing application. It would be preferred if by default everything is blacklisted (`default-src: 'none'`) and then whitelist all required resources (f.e.: `img-src: 'self'`).

Now when the icons are included from a sheet of SVG icons is there no tag which allows whitelisting in Firefox (57 & 58), while the `img-src` directive works for Chrome (63) and Opera (49). Hence this would force me to weaken the default tag, which I would prefer not to. Is this a Firefox specific bug, or is our code violating some standards causing this undefined behavior?

Here is the code to reproduce the behaviour.

HTML which causes only Firefox to block the image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
            default-src 'none';
            child-src 'self';
            connect-src 'self';
            font-src 'self';
            frame-src 'self';
            img-src 'self';
            manifest-src 'self'; 
            media-src 'self'; 
            object-src 'self'; 
            script-src 'self'; 
            style-src 'self'; 
            worker-src 'self';
        ">
    </head> 
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="img.svg#circle"></use>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

While this does work in Firefox, but has a significantly weakened CSP policy:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
            default-src 'self';
        ">
    </head>
    <body>
        <svg>
            <use xlink:href="img.svg#circle"></use>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

img.svg

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="display:none;">
    <symbol id="circle" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <g>
            <circle cx="32" cy="32" r="32" />
        </g>
    </symbol>
</svg>
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1303364

Comment: I think Chrome is wrong to allow img-src for <use> references FWIW.

Comment: If you're that concerned about security, then the CSP should be in the *header* not within the HTML file itself. You can then seta custom CSP for `svg` file types, such as in your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: @Martin thanks for noticing it, I just created this toy example to be able to easily share and reproduce it, in normal development are HTTP headers used.

Comment: Then you can set a custom CSP for `svg` file types (giving it a custom `default`). It doesn't solve the problem but you can work around it.